# iPhone app - Use pre populated database or rely on a web service?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios5

I'm working on an iPhone app that allows the user to browse a product catalogue. Potentially, this catalogue could hold 1000+ items. Every product is related to a Brand, and have some attributes such as color, size etc.

I'm think of pre-populating a SQLlite DB and including it in my app's bundle, then, like in [CoreDataBooks example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_15), on the first launch I'll use the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`to check if the database has been created, and if not copy the default database to the desired location and move on.

But the product catalogue needs to be updated, and since the database will hold other information that the user added - like add a product to favorite etc., I don't want to overwrite the database once it has been initialized (from the default).

So I was thinking about using the network, calling a webservice, but wouldn't that be way to heavy on the network? It should be fast to browse products, and I fear that relying on webservices will slow down things unacceptably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the database, there is no other way for you, but to download it from the net. But you don't need to make it slow by downloading it right when user browses the catalogue–instead, you just check if there is something new on the server every time user launches the app, or some other periodical moment - and when the user starts browsinh, you store is already up-to-date. That's it!

Here is a great article on fetching data in background with Core Data, by Marcus Zarra

http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/

Comment: So you're saying I should combine the two approaches I outlined. Use a database within the app, and do the updates by downloading new data over the network and then add/update/delete in the database to reflect the updates?

Comment: Yes,that's really convenient way for obtaining results you need

Comment: Just prepopulate with all that you have at the moment of shipping, and then update it

Comment: Alright. And it'd be fine to just kick off a new thread when the app starts, fetch updates over the network, and start populating changes - even though the user might be browsing around?

Comment: Yes,that's right.read the link in my answer.It's really awesome